# Client Portal - Secure File Sharing

Tags: permissions

I am thinking of using EE to create a client portal site.  Each client will have access to documents and information (such as contracts and expiry dates etc).  Obviously there is a key desire to have permissions in place that only allow logged in users from the specific client to have access to the documents.  This would extend to not having a link to the documents for download that can be used shared / discovered by an external party but can only be accessed by logged-in users with that level of permission (so it might be that within a given client we need different levels of permission - you might not want a support person to see a pricing document for example, but they may need to see a support agreement).

My question is whether or not there is a well established design pattern for EE that would allow this type of portal to be easily created using pretty much "off the shelf" EE and add-ons?

Thanks in advance!